# Importing and processing a spreadsheet on Google App Engine

Tags: python, excel, google-app-engine, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet full of information and one time only I need to put this data into the Datastore by reading the rows and creating model entities out of all of the data.  Each row is an entity and each column is a different property.

I am a little confused how exactly I can put the data into a form that is process-able by GAE and then what I should use to process the spreadsheet in python.  I can easily move my data, which is currently in Excel, to Google Docs if that makes things easier but I am still not sure what to do from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is to publish the spreadsheet. See this blogpost: http://blog.pamelafox.org/2010/08/importing-data-from-spreadsheets-to-app.html

Another method is to download the the spreadsheet as a CSV and upload this CSV with the app engine bulkloader.

Comment: thanks for the helpful link.  do you have any idea how to get the data to turn into a json link? the article doesn't go into much depth.  here is my google doc link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsZE8AuY2VhrdGxDMmpoR3BIYy1vdTBWYTZBcEtoRkE#gid=0

Comment: The answer is in Pamelas blog post : To get the URL for your own public spreadsheet, just change the spreadsheet key (the long string there) and the worksheet ID (the first sheet is always 'od6').

Comment: I am sorry if I seem thick but I read through that and what do I change the long string to?

Comment: You also have to publish your spreadsheet. Publish is in the File Menu of your spreadsheet.

Comment: Here is your link, after publishing it as an RSS and using Pamala's recipe: https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AsZE8AuY2VhrdGxDMmpoR3BIYy1vdTBWYTZBcEtoRkE/od6/public/basic?alt=json